# If the equation $x^2 = (2^{2^y} + 1)^s + 2^t$ holds, can $t$ be odd?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, conjectures

If $x, y, s, t \in \mathbb{N}$ and the equation $$x^2 = (2^{2^y} + 1)^s + 2^t$$ holds, can $t$ be odd if $s$ is odd?

<s>I know that $t$ cannot be odd when $s=1$. How about if $s>1$?</s> **Added September 10 2017**: I was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exhaustive search but i found one example when $s>1$.

for $s=1$ i get many examples.

$s=3,y=2,t=7,x=71$.

for $s>3$ it did not give a small examples, i checked for all $t<100$.

Comment: Thanks, @Ahmad!  But would you mind sharing everything that you have found thus far?

Comment: $s=3,y=2,t=7,x=71$ is the only example i found after doing a small search, i did not look deeply into the question,but i will.

Comment: Okay, thanks again @Ahmad!

Comment: Sorry for bugging you again @Ahmad, but can you give the smallest example for which $s = 1$ and $t$ is odd?  Thanks!

Comment: $s=1,y=2,t=3,x=5$